# How to make element disappear once its created with event listener (pure Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I've been googling for hours and trying out different methods and can't get this to work.

I'm trying to do is: if there is no box, then add a box. If there is a box where you're clicking, then remove the box.

So far, it removes a box but automatically adds a new one, leaving a box on the screen when there should be none.

How do I get the box removed when someone clicks on it -- in pure Javascript.

Here is my jsfiddle so you can see what's happening. https://jsfiddle.net/on6z83ko/10/

Code:

```
addEventListener('click', createBox);

function createBox(event){

    var box = document.createElement('div');

    document.body.appendChild(box);

    box.className = "box";
    box.style.visibility="visible";    
    box.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
    box.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';

    var mouse = event.currentTarget;
    mouse.click = (mouse.click || 0) +1;

    console.log(mouse.click);

    box.addEventListener("click", function(){

        var deleteBox = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

        if(deleteBox){
            box.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The click event isn't stopping at the box when you click on a box. Look into event bubbling and capturing. I think you'll answer your own question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

#### [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/on6z83ko/23/)

This was the key-point:

```
if(target.classList.contains('box')){
    target.remove();
    }
```

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem i will update the answer with more details.

Comment: Yes, thank you, exactly what I was looking for. So, if I have the understanding correct, you code means if the event target with class attributes is already on the page/body, remove that specific target/box.

Comment: Glad I could be of help :) Basically in your code you asked `if(target === box)` box being the new **div** you just made. Instead I asked does the _target_, that I clicked, have a class of **box**? If it does remove the _target_ (which can only be a div that I've just clicked and that has the class **box**)

Comment: And your code keep on creating an empty `.box` div, each time you click on the document... Even if you don't want to do that.

Comment: I thought OP wanted to that @n1kkou. _"if there is no box, then add a box. If there is a box where you're clicking, then remove the box"_. I might have misunderstood the OP though.

Comment: If a box exists and you click on it, it should be removed. But in the same time, keeping that piece of code, you keep on creating a box, even though you remove the one you click.

Comment: @n1kkou This seemed more fun. Well Jasmine if you want to keep adding the boxes this solution is for you, otherwise n1kkou has you covered. Next time n1kkou I would appreciate criticism first and downvotes later :)

Comment: I downvoted your answer for `classList` support starting with IE10

Comment: @n1kkou Thanks for the info, now I've learned something as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('click', createBox);

function createBox(event){
    var target = event.target;

    if(target.className === 'box'){
        target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
    } else {
        var box = document.createElement('div');

        box.className = "box";
        box.style.visibility="visible";
        box.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
        box.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';

        document.body.appendChild(box);
    }
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that this solution is related to your context. If you have multiple class names, it will break and you will need to use a regex to check if the class name `box` is contained.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I'm going to study this and practice more.

Comment: You can start by writting down on a piece of paper, the logic behind your actions. Then you will figure it out, how and when to check if the box exists and when to create/append it to the document. You can also do this with `createDocumentFragment()` method on the `document` object.

Answer (score 0):

From how I read the question, this will not add a box when there is one on the screen, and remove it when it 
is clicked, then add another on the next click.
https://jsfiddle.net/on6z83ko/40/

```
  addEventListener('click', createBox);
  var box;
  var boxBounds = {
    Left: 0,
    Right: 0,
    Top: 0,
    Bottom: 0
  };


  function createBox(event) {

    if (box == null) {
      box = document.createElement('div');
      var target = event.target;

      document.body.appendChild(box);

      box.className = "box";
      box.style.visibility = "visible";
      box.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
      box.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';
      return;
    }

    //alert(event.pageX + "," + event.pageY);

    boxBounds.Left = parseInt(box.style.left, 10);
    boxBounds.Right = boxBounds.Left + 100;
    boxBounds.Top = parseInt(box.style.top, 10);
    boxBounds.Bottom = boxBounds.Top + 100;

    //alert("");
    //alert("L" + boxBounds.Left + " R" + boxBounds.Right + " T" + boxBounds.Top + " B" + boxBounds.Bottom);

    //remove if in bounds of box
    if ((event.pageX >= boxBounds.Left) && (event.pageX <= boxBounds.Right) &&
      (event.pageY >= boxBounds.Top) && (event.pageY <= boxBounds.Bottom)) {
      //alert("InBOX");
      document.body.removeChild(box);
      box = null;
      return;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create an even handler on your box and stop propagation to prevent main click event, and remove the box in that event handler. I cant edit your code from my phone :(